# My onTouch method is not doing its proper fucntion

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am making a Android app. The objective is to make circles that when touched something happens. Here is the onTouch method

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   int x = (int) event.getX();
   int y = (int) event.getY();
   if(isInsideCircle(x, y) ==  true){
      //Do your things here
       if(redColor == lastColor){
          Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), YouFailed.class);
          v.getContext().startActivity(i);
       } else {
           addPoints++;
       }
   }else {

   }
   return true;
}
```

This part of the code is the thing that is not functioning properly here is the entire class below.

```
public class DrawingView extends View{



    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
    RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 0);

    private static final int w = 100;
    public static int lastColor = Color.BLACK;
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private final int radius = 230;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static int redColor = Color.RED;
    public static int greenColor = Color.GREEN;
    int randomWidth = 0;
    int randomHeight = 0;
    public static int addPoints = 0;


    private final Runnable updateCircle = new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            lastColor = random.nextInt(2) == 1 ? redColor : greenColor;
            paint.setColor(lastColor);
            invalidate();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

        }
    };

    @Override 
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        handler.post(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // your other stuff here
        if(random == null){
            randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
            randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));
        }else {
            randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
            randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidth, randomHeight + radius/2f, radius, paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(150);
        canvas.drawText("Score: " + addPoints, 120, 300, paint);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   int x = (int) event.getX();
   int y = (int) event.getY();
   if(isInsideCircle(x, y) ==  true){
      //Do your things here
       if(redColor == lastColor){
          Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), YouFailed.class);
          v.getContext().startActivity(i);
       } else {
           addPoints++;
       }
   }else {

   }
   return true;
}

public boolean isInsideCircle(int x, int y){
  if ((((x - randomWidth)*(x - randomWidth)) + ((y - randomHeight)*(y - randomHeight))) < ((radius)*(radius)))
    return true;
  return false;    
}











}
```

Comment: and...???  is it all?

Comment: no it is not would you like me to post the entire package

Comment: what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: The problem is when a green or red circle is clicked nothing happens. Nothing is added to addPoints and the activity does not change.

Comment: so probably isInsideCircle() doesn't work as expected

Comment: no definantly not that

Comment: To detect touch, you need to Override `onTouchEvent()` method in your class. `onTouch()` will never be called in your case.